# Multi-File Upload with HTML 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, file-upload

I have a web application that currently uses Flash. That application allows the user to select multiple files from their computer and press "upload". We then upload those files to our server. I need to update our application to use HTML 5.

My question is, what is the recommended approach for uploading multiple files with HTML 5? I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 on my backend.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use this in, let's say, the form that let's the user to upload files:

```
<input name="uploads[]" type="file" multiple="true">
```

Then, in the backend you can go through the uploads as an array that contain the different files.

Comment: What is with the array syntax? Is that actually supported as a valid name?

Comment: It's not related to HTML5, but it's used for the backend I use (PHP) - By doing so PHP will construct an array. Otherwise it would get just the last file. I suppose you can adapt that to the ASP.NET syntax.

Comment: @user609886 I have an example that uses Plupload. See https://github.com/tommiller85/Image-Bank-MVC