# ASP.NET MVC 3: Support for HTML5 multiple file upload?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

Can I use:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple="multiple" />
```

and bind it to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    ...
}
```

I'm writing a web app for modern browsers and don't have to worry about IE so I'd like to avoid using Flash. Right now `files` is always null when I post the form. Is there any way to get this to work in MVC 3?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-File Upload with HTML 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713802/multi-file-upload-with-html-5)

Comment: You will probably need to create a custom model binder.

Comment: Or make the signature `public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you have your encoding set correctly in your form?

I believe you still need:

```
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }
```

In the form declaration to ensure the browser can post files.

For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: OK, spoke too soon. Went back to double check and I had a type-o there that was preventing the file from posting!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't one use the Request.Files for backward compatibility as follows:

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
{
  string UpoadedFilesFolder = "YourServerFolder";
  string fileName ="";
  byte[] fileData=null;
  foreach (HttpPostedFileBase uf in Request.Files)
  {
    HttpPostedFileBase UpoadedFile = uf;
    if (uf.ContentLength > 0)
    {
      fileName = Path.GetFileName(UpoadedFile.FileName);
      using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(UpoadedFile.InputStream))
      {
        fileData = br.ReadBytes((int)UpoadedFile.InputStream.Length);
      }
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(UpoadedFilesFolder), fi.FileName), FileMode.Create))
      {
        fs.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
      }
    }
  }
  return Content("OK");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Index View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload","home", FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="files" value=" " multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" name="btUpload" value="Upload" />
}
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = files.Count();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

And files contains uploaded files - works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

This won't work:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase uf in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase UpoadedFile = uf;
}
```

Should do like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
  HttpPostedFileBase UpoadedFile = Request.Files[i];
}
```